# Como fazer scale de uma div sem alterar os elementos filho?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, css-transições

Como faço para que a opacidade e o tamanho do conteúdo dentro dos parágrafos não se altere quando ocorre a transição?!

```css
#quadrados{
    padding-top: 2vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30.5vw;
    background:url(imgs/parede.jpg);
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.quadrado{
    width: 18.5vw;
    margin-left: 5vw;
    height: 18.5vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 1vw;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.quadrado p{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 8.2vw;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 2vw;
}


.quadrado{
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}


.quadrado:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<section id="quadrados">
        <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado1">
            <p>O texto altera</p>
        </div>
        <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado2">
            <p>Quero que o texto</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado3">
            <p>Permaneça</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado4">
            <p>Inalterado</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Retire toda a referencia `opacity` do CSS

Comment: o tamanho do texto irá aumentar de igual forma...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode trocar `opacity` por `rgba` nos atributos `border`, ficando assim:

```
.quadrado{
    width: 18.5vw;
    margin-left: 5vw;
    height: 18.5vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 1vw;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

.quadrado:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

E para evitar que o `transform` afete o filho, pode colocar dentro dos elementos filhos outro `transform` quando ocorrer o `:hover`, por exemplo:

```
.quadrado:hover > * {
    transform: scale(.9);
}
```

O `.9` compensa o `.1` de aumento usado no `scale(1.1)`, ou seja, no elemento `.quadrado` é aumentado `+0.1` e no elemento(s) filho(s) é reduzido `-0.1`

> **Nota:**
>
> Apliquei o `transition` para os elementos filhos `.quadrado > *` para evitar o efeito de aumenta e diminui nos elementos filhos
>
> ```
> .quadrado, .quadrado > * {
>    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
> }
> ```

---

### Primeiro exemplo

Deve ficar assim:

> **Nota:** A imagem https://i.stack.imgur.com/MinZ1.png é somente para teste

```css
#quadrados{
    padding-top: 2vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30.5vw;
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MinZ1.png);
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.quadrado{
    width: 18.5vw;
    margin-left: 5vw;
    height: 18.5vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 1vw;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

.quadrado p{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 8.2vw;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 2vw;
}

.quadrado, .quadrado > * {
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.quadrado:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.quadrado:hover > * {
    transform: scale(.9);
}
```

```html
<section id="quadrados">
    <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado1">
        <p>O texto altera</p>
    </div>
    <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado2">
        <p>Quero que o texto</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado3">
        <p>Permaneça</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado4">
        <p>Inalterado</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

### Segundo exemplo

O efeito do `transform` ainda causa algum *blur*, fora que o AP (autor da pergunta) afirmou é necessário `opacity` pois esta usando imagens de fundo em cada quadro adicionando mais um elemento

O elemento .foto ficará com `position: absolute;` e ficará relativo ao elemento pai, também foi necessário remover o `overflow: hidden;` do `.quadrado`, então com isto:

```
.quadrado:hover .foto {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    opacity: .3;
}
```

Foi necessário aplicar o `z-index` no elemento `.quadrado p` para que ele não fique abaixo:

```
.quadrado p{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 101; /*necessário para que fique na frente*/
```

O `opacity` e o `transform` só são aplicados ao elemento `.foto`, segue o código completo:

```css
#quadrados{
    padding-top: 2vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30.5vw;
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MinZ1.png);
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.quadrado{
    width: 18.5vw;
    margin-left: 5vw;
    height: 18.5vw;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative; /*posiciona a imagem dentro do quadrado*/
}

.quadrado p{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 101; /*necessário para que fique na frente*/
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 8.2vw;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 2vw;
}

.quadrado .foto {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 1vw;
    border: 2px solid black;
    opacity: .9;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;

    background-size: cover; /* a imagem ocupa o elemento todo */
}

.quadrado:hover .foto {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<section id="quadrados">
    <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado1">
        <p>O texto altera</p>
        <div class="foto" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTaZV.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado2">
        <p>Quero que o texto</p>
        <div class="foto" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo2KL.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado3">
        <p>Permaneça</p>
        <div class="foto" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTaZV.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado4">
        <p>Inalterado</p>
        <div class="foto" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo2KL.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Já tinha encontrado uma solução parecida e o problema que todos se queixam é do blur no texto durante a transformação, o rgba está fora de questão, eu meti aqui uma div com border como exemplo, na realidade essas divs vão estar preenchidas por imagens... Muito obrigado pela sugestão, vou aplica-la enquanto não encontrar um método mais eficaz

Comment: @Droopy as imagens na div são `<img>` ou backgrounds?

Comment: são backgrounds

Comment: @Droopy vou editar, tenho uma sugestão pra evitar o blur e ao mesmo tempo usar o opacity

Comment: a minha ideia é fazer algo parecido com o menu feito de quadrados neste site (scroll down maximo) http://www.wix.com/mystunningwebsites/hiker?experiment_id=cake_33315425%5E214&utm_campaign=af_17%40www.webcreate.io%2F&utm_medium=paid_referral&utm_source=affiliate

Comment: @Droopy resposta editada, veja o segundo exemplo

Comment: Era exactamente isso que eu procurava, obrigado pela ajuda ficou óptimo, só tenho mais um pequeno pormenor a ajustar, quero o texto inicialmente escondido por isso usei  visibility:hidden; no paragrafo e no hover usei visibility:visible; mas gostava de ter uma transição suave de hidden para visible e uma transição instantânea de visible para hidden, para isso usei o transition: .2s ease-in; mas quando tiro o rato da imagem o texto ainda fica visivel 0.2 segundos, o que devo utilizar no transition para ter a animação apenas quando passo o rato por cima e mal tire o rato o texto desapareça?!

Comment: @Droopy veja se é isto o que deseja https://jsfiddle.net/hxqyeebt/

Comment: Não era bem dessa forma mas gostei do efeito por isso irei utilizar =))

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar um *pseudo-elemento* `::before` que irá sofrer o `scale`, deixando o conteúdo da `div` inerte.

`pseudo-elementos` são como *elementos-filhos* criados virtualmente, onde você pode alterar seus estilos no CSS de forma independente, sem alterar o elemento que os criou (**[saiba mais sobre `pseudo-elementos`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elementos)**).

```css
#quadrados{
    padding-top: 2vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30.5vw;
    background:url(imgs/parede.jpg);
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.quadrado{
    width: 20.6vw;
    margin-left: 3vw;
    height: 20.6vw;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.quadrado p{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 9vw;
    font-size: 2vw;
}

.quadrado::before{
   content:'';
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    width: 18.5vw;
    height: 18.5vw;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 1vw;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1vw;
    left: 1vw;

}

.quadrado:hover::before{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<section id="quadrados">
     <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado1">
         <p>O texto altera</p>
     </div>
     <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado2">
         <p>Quero que o texto</p>
     </div>
     
     <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado3">
         <p>Permaneça</p>
     </div>
     
     <div class="quadrado" id="quadrado4">
         <p>Inalterado</p>
     </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: colei a parte do código alterada para o meu Brackets e por alguma razão o hover não funciona

Comment: @Droopy veja se não é problema de cache do CSS.

Comment: @Droopy veja se o código foi corretamente copiado... a mínima diferença pode não funcionar. CSS é muito chato nesse aspecto.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, não tinha erros de cópia, pelo menos eu não reparei em nenhum,comecei a estudar html/css há pouco tempo e achei o método do @Guilherme Nascimento P. mais simples, pelo menos eu compreendi melhor daquela forma do que usando o ::before

Comment: @Droopy tranquilo. Fico contente que tenha achado a solução. Mas quando vc aprender os pseudo-elementos, certamente verá que é bem mais simples trabalhar com eles nesses casos.