# Elementos filhos recebendo opacidade mesmo com uso de rgba

Tags: css, css3

Como eu posso aplicar uma opacidade diferente em um elemento filho.
No exemplo abaixo está funcionando corretamente, porém o mesmo código não funciona com:

> Chrome Versão 71.0.3578.80
>
> Firefox Quantum 63.0.

```css
body {
    background: url('http://www.onoirtoronto.com/onoir/wp-content/uploads/website-bg.jpg') center no-repeat;
}

.pai {
    margin:  0 auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.filho {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
    <div class="filho">

    </div>
</div>
```

[image: O código dentro do meu ambiente]

Comment: Outra que aborda o mesmo assunto, mas com propriedade diferente https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264862/como-fazer-scale-de-uma-div-sem-alterar-os-elementos-filho

Comment: Mais uma mas com outra propriedade tb https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/346258/fundo-com-blur-e-div-do-meio-sem/

Comment: O problema é que o rgba também está aplicando opacidade aos filhos, eu já tinha encontrado esses posts e tentado resolver através dos mesmos!

Comment: Mas eu não vi nada com RGBA nesse codigo ai que vc postou... Ou então de mais detalhes do seu problema

Comment: Eu não levei em consideração o rgba, pois pensei que não fosse a solução, eu alterei no jsfiddle com rgba e funcionou na pagina do jsfiddle, porém o mesmo exemplo não funciona nem no firefox nem no chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base no comentário do autor fiz esse modelo usando RGBA. Assim não uso `opacity`, e sim uso o *alpha* do `rgba()` no `background`

Funciona no Chrome, FireFox etc

```css
body {
    background: url('http://www.onoirtoronto.com/onoir/wp-content/uploads/website-bg.jpg') center no-repeat;
}
.pai {
    margin:  0 auto;
    background: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.5);
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.filho {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
 <div class="filho">

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Reformulei a pergunta, ao que me parece estou fazendo certo, porém nos meus navegadores não estão funcionando.

Comment: @Rech cara esse código é pra funcionar até no IE8 não tem possibilidade alguma de não estar funcionando ai. A não ser que o seu monitor tenha alguma configuração de Brilho ou Contraste que não esta deixando vc notar a transparência... Sugiro vc testar em outro monitor ou até mesmo pelo seu celular entrando aqui no link da pergunta e executando o código.

Comment: O engraçado, que nessa funcionalidade de preview do stackoverflow, que aliás quero agradecer, eu não sabia da existência dela, nele funciona perfeitamente, a opacidade está sendo aplicada corretamente, porém o mesmo código nesses dois navegadores na minha maquina não funcionam.

Comment: @Rech provavelmente é pq tem mais CSS ai no seu código que está interferindo nisso... Te sugiro fazer um teste rápido criando um arquivo novo separado e colocando exatamente o código do exemplo.

Comment: Acabei de adicionar uma imagem do código exemplo em funcionamento na minha maquina

Comment: Encontrei o erro, eu não removi a propriedade opacity do elemento pai depois de aplicar o rgba, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @Rech  sem problemas jovem! Boa sorte no projeto!